# What's the difference between CONFIG_R8169 and CONFIG_R8169_VLAN?

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules

.config from `/usr/src/linux-2.6.38.8` contains:

```
CONFIG_R8169=m
CONFIG_R8169_VLAN=y
```

What's the difference between `CONFIG_R8169` and `CONFIG_R8169_VLAN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONFIG_R8169_VLAN` enables support for the VLAN/802.1Q code in the r8169 driver. For an introduction in VLANs see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q

A small tip for the future, if you need to determine what a specific config option in the kernel does you should have a look at the integrated help text, e.g: [help text for `R8169_VLAN`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/R8169_VLAN.html). Sometimes it also helps to look at the driver itself and check what the config option does.